# Constructor with multiple arguments with Ninject

Tags: c#, ninject, ioc-container

I am tring to use [Ninject](http://www.ninject.org/) as a IoC container but could not understand how to create an instance of a class that has more than 1 parameter in the constructor. Basically I have a service interface for authentication in a PCL library and its implementation in a WP8 project that receives in the constructor the cosumer key, secret and baseAddress:

```
//On PCL project
public interface IAuthorizationService {
 bool Authenticate();
}

//On WP8 Project
pubilc class MyAuthenticator : IAuthorizationService {
 public MyAuthenticator(string consumerKey, string consumerSecret, string baseAddress) { ... }
 public bool Authenticate() { ... }
}
```

Now I need to configure [Ninject](http://www.ninject.org/) module so I can get an instance of IAuthorizationService. 
If my class had no constructors I would do:

```
internal class Module : NinjectModule {
 public override void Load() {
  this.Bind<IAuthorizationService>().To<MyAuthenticator>();
 }
}
```

If it had fixed values for the constructor I would do:

```
internal class Module : NinjectModule {
 public override void Load() {
  this.Bind<IAuthorizationService>().To<MyAuthenticator>().WithConstructorArgument( */* fixed argument here*/* );
 }
}
```

And to get an instance `Module.Get<IAuthorizationService>()`

**But what if the constructor parameters cannot be resolved at compile time? How to pass the paramenters? How should the bind code be?**

*Edited to claryfy the question.*

Comment: Why the downvote? should have at least commented so I could change the question...

Comment: it's probably because they felt that this question is easily answered by looking at the docs: https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Dependency-Injection-With-Ninject

Comment: No, it is not! If you look at the docs all the constructor parameters are "injectable" too. My constructor has strings parameters.

Comment: to be precise, string is just another type which is just as "injectable" as any other type (interface, class). however, due to it's broad use it's not really suitable for injection. The same would be true for an `ICurrency` or `ICultureInfo` interface, too. Usually broadly-used types are passed as parameter or retrieved from a factory/provider (which is injected), p.Ex. `ICurrencyProvider.GetUsersCurrency()` or `ICultureInfoProvider.GetCurrentUiCulture()`. It quite the same concept as with entities: you usually don't inject an entity, rather you pass it along, or retrieve it from a repository.

Comment: I upvoted this because I agree, the docs are garbage because they're tailored to work perfectly to the example they're showing. __Concise__ real-world examples are much more favorable.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's very easy. No matter how many constructor arguments, the binding stays the same:

```
Bind<IAuthorizationService>().To<MyAuthenticator>();
```

Let's say `MyAuthenticator` had a constructor with one parameter of type `IFoo`.
All you got to do is tell ninject how it can resolve/create an `IFoo`. Again, very simple:

```
Bind<IFoo>().To<Foo>();
```

You don't need `WithConstructorArgument` ever, *except* in case you want to override the default behavior of ninject. Let's say `MyAuthenticator` has a parameter of type `IFoo` plus another parameter `string seed` which you want to configure specifically. All you'd need is:

```
Bind<IFoo>().To<Foo>();
Bind<IAuthorizationService>().To<MyAuthenticator>()
    .WithConstructorArgument("seed", "initialSeedValue");
```

no need to specify the value of the `IFoo` parameter!

Comment: That is the problem, my constructor has string parameters and I dont know their value on Bind time.

Comment: Where do you get the values of the string parameters from? I reckon you might need a factory. Why don't you pass these string parameters as argument to the `Authenticate()` method?

Comment: 2 of then are from configuration files so I passed then  with ´WithConstructorArgument()´ method. The other one depends on user input.

Comment: Then you would need to consider using a factory (have a look at ninject factory extension). Or otherwise, inject an object which is a "placeholder" for the user input. Bind it `.InSingletonScope()` and have the UI set the value and after that the `AuthorizationService` read it..

Answer (score 2):

Ninject can inject more than one constructor arguments like:

```
 Bind<IMyClass>().To<MyClass>().InSingletonScope()
                .WithConstructorArgument("customerName", "Daenerys Targeryan")
                .WithConstructorArgument("customerAddress", "King's Landing");
```

It does not change how the binding works.