# Ninject dynamically constructor parameters

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject

In a WebApi project I have a class `SyncProductsHelper`. This class has two properties, a constructor and some methods:

```
public class SyncProductsHelper
{
    public int iId { get; set; }
    public string sId { get; set; }

    public SyncProductsHelper(int iId, string sId)
    {
        this.iId = iId;
        this.sId = sId;;
    }

    public ind ChangeSomething(int a)
    {
        iId = a;
    }
}
```

Now I'm trying to enable DI in my project, so I've installed Ninject and set it up. I write an interface `ISyncProductsHelper`:

```
public interface ISyncProductsHelper
{
    void ChangeSomething(int a);
}
```

And do the binding in my resolver:

```
_kernel.Bind<ISyncProductsHelper>().To<SyncProductsHelper>();
```

In my controller which uses this SyncProductsHelper, I setup a constructor and a field:

```
private readonly ISyncProductsHelper _syncHelper;
public SyncProductController(ISyncProductsHelper syncHelper)
{
    this._syncHelper = syncHelper;
}
```

The problem is, that I don't know where to set the iId and sId parameters which my current implementation of ISyncProductsHelper needs. They are provided dynamically by the user to the ApiController through a Post, so apparently I cannot use `WithConstructorArgument` as I've seen elsewhere.
The paramters are essential to the class, but should I instead just set them with setter-methods - or what to do.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25667834/constructor-with-multiple-arguments-with-ninject/25700827#25700827

Comment: With `ApiController`, are you referring to the `SyncProductController`? If the values are not known upon instanciation but only later, upon execution, you can't use ctor injection. You should pass with a method, like `.Initialize(...)` or (depending on what the helper is doing) with the `ChangeSomething` method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ninject can't resolve the dependencies `iId` and `sId` because they are not available to be bound until your API method is called, but by then it's too late in the binding chain. When you receive a post to the method, an instance of `SyncProductController` is instantiated and then Ninject attempts to instantiate a `SyncProductsHelper`, but it can't because it doesn't know where or how to find its dependencies at that point.

I would suggest one of two options:

1. Refactor your implementation to make `SyncProductsHelper` act on `iId` and `sId` in some other way that would allow you to have a parameterless constructor. Perhaps creating a new class representing `iId` and `sId` that it acts on as another parameter for `ChangeSomething`. Does `SyncProductsHelper` need to remember the state of these fields?
2. Consider not using dependency injection at all for this particular class. From your code it looks like `SyncProductsHelper` is purely just working with primitives, so you could simply create a new instance from your Web API methods directly. You can still easily unit test this class because it doesn't have any external dependencies of its own.

Comment: Thanks. #1: I don't fully understand, why I'm kind of the only person who has this problem. Isn't it normal to create contructors like that? :-) #2 - it's a pretty simplified version of my code.

Comment: It's perfectly fine to use constructors in that way, but dependency injection requires its own set of rules that tend to guide your class design. I've updated my answer to help clarify :)